# What are the minimum requirements for passing medical for PPL?

Tags: medical, ppl, caa-uk-regulations

Where can I find the UK requirements to pass the medical exam for a PPL?

Basically I would like to check my health and all the requirements with **any** doctor - I have health insurance plan, and when I know that I meet all the criteria I go back to the aviation doctor for checking and issuing the certificate.

Comment: Related: https://www.caa.co.uk/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=4294973027

Comment: Have you gone to see an aviation medical examiner? You should direct this to him/her.

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking here. The UK medical standards are [available online](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aeromedical-Examiners/Medical-standards/Pilots-(EASA)/By-class/Medical-standards-for-EASA-pilots/) and I assume you could go to any doctor with that information for a checkup. It sounds like you aren't happy with the examination and costs so far, but I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: @Pondlife what I was asking is the information that you just provided, for the purpose you have just mentioned  `I assume you could go to any doctor with that information for a checkup`. If you bother to put that in an answer I am glad to accept it, otherwise, thank you much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! I simplified your question to make it more focused on your main point, but you can just roll back or edit again if my changes aren't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UK aviation medical standards are [available online](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aeromedical-Examiners/Medical-standards/Pilots-(EASA)/By-class/Medical-standards-for-EASA-pilots/), so I assume you could go to any doctor with that information for a checkup.